# How does the tf.scatter_update() work inside the while_loop()

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to update a `tf.Variable` inside a `tf.while_loop()`, using `tf.scatter_update()`. However, the result is the initial value instead of the updated value. Here is the sample code of what I am trying to do:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf

def cond(sequence_len, step):
    return tf.less(step,sequence_len)

def body(sequence_len, step): 

    begin = tf.get_variable("begin",[3],dtype=tf.int32,initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0))
    begin = tf.scatter_update(begin,1,step,use_locking=None)

    tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
   return (sequence_len, step+1)

with tf.Graph().as_default():

    sess = tf.Session()
    step = tf.constant(0)
    sequence_len  = tf.constant(10)
    _,step, = tf.while_loop(cond,
                    body,
                    [sequence_len, step], 
                    parallel_iterations=10, 
                    back_prop=True, 
                    swap_memory=False, 
                    name=None)

    begin = tf.get_variable("begin",[3],dtype=tf.int32)

    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)

    print(sess.run([begin,step]))
```

The result is: `[array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32), 10]`. However, I think the result should be `[0, 0, 10]`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I suggest running `sess.run(step)` before running `sess.run(begin)`. The order of evaluation is not defined here and it may cause issues. I had this issue with `scatter_update` and `tf.float` type when I was running on GPU.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that nothing in the loop body depends on your `tf.scatter_update()` op, so it is never executed. The easiest way to make it work is to add a control dependency on the update to the return values:

```
def body(sequence_len, step): 
    begin = tf.get_variable("begin",[3],dtype=tf.int32,initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0))
    begin = tf.scatter_update(begin, 1, step, use_locking=None)
    tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()

    with tf.control_dependencies([begin]):
        return (sequence_len, step+1)
```

Note that this problem isn't unique to loops in TensorFlow. If you had just defined an `tf.scatter_update()` op called `begin` but call `sess.run()` on it, or something that depends on it, then the update won't happen. When you're using the [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#while_loop) there's no way to run the operations defined in the loop body directly, so the easiest way to get a side effect is to add a control dependency.

Note that the final result is `[0, 9, 0]`: each iteration assigns the current step to `begin[1]`, and in the last iteration the value of the current step is `9` (the condition is false when `step == 10`).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I didn't know about this.