# Update Tensor at index in a tf.while_loop

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch

Ok so I want to replicate this `keep[count] = i` Pytorch code in Tensorflow, this is happening within a `tf.while_loop` both `count` and `i` are tensors.

```
keep = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(tf.size(scores), tf.int64))
count = 0
idx = tf.argsort(scores, axis=0)#scores.sort(0)  # sort in ascending order
idx = idx[-top_k:]
...

def loop_body(idx, keep, count, ...)
    i = idx[-1]  # index of current largest val
    keep = tf.scatter_update(keep, count, i)

tf.while_loop(loop_cond, loop_body, loop_vars)
```

This is what I'm trying to do `keep = tf.scatter_update(keep, count, i)`, this unfortunately raises a `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_lazy_read`

Comment: This error shows that the input of `tf.scatter_update` should be type `Variable` rather than type `Tensor`. You need to provide more example code.

Comment: Here @giser_yugang I added more details

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236479/update-a-variable-with-tf-while-loop-in-tensorflow.  You can refer it.