# How to use tf.scatter_update within a tf.while_loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have `tf.while_loop` in which it is conditioned based on an element inside a `tf.Variable`. The problem is when I used `tf.scatter_update`, I get the following error message (NOTE: it works fine when I use `tf.add`):

```
---> 11   var = tf.scatter_update(var, [0], tf.add(var, tf.constant([1.0])))

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_lazy_read'
```

The simplified code is as follows (NOTE: I cannot use `tf.add` because I want to update only one element inside the variable tensor so I have to use `tf.scatter_update`):

```
def func(var1, cons):
  var1, _ = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [var1, x], return_same_structure=True)
  with tf.control_dependencies([var1, _]):
    return var1

def cond(var, cons):
  return tf.reduce_all(tf.less(var,cons))

def body(var, cons):
  var = tf.scatter_update(var, [0], tf.add(var, tf.constant([1.0])))
  # Works fine when using --> var = tf.add(var, tf.constant([1.0]))
  return (var, cons)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  x = tf.constant([10.0])
  m = tf.Variable([2.0])
  b = func(m, x)
  init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
  sess.run(init)
  print sess.run(b)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236479/update-a-variable-with-tf-while-loop-in-tensorflow/52243130

Comment: The solution in that link is not to pass it as function parameter, however, in my use case it is coming as function parameter (it is part of a bigger code).
Maybe I need to update the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `tf.get_variable`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def func(var1, cons):
    var1, _ = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [var1, cons], return_same_structure=True)
    with tf.control_dependencies([var1, _]):
        return var1

def cond(var, cons):
    return tf.reduce_all(tf.less(var,cons))

def body(var, cons):
    var = tf.get_variable(name="m",initializer=[2.0])
    var = tf.scatter_update(var, [0], tf.add(var, tf.constant([1.0])))
    # var = tf.add(var, tf.constant([1.0]))
    return (var, cons)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.constant([10.0])
    m = tf.Variable([2.0],name='m')
    b = func(m, x)
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(b))

[10.]
```